# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in "..\index.php" on line 6

Tags: php, diseño-de-clases, namespace

Antes que nada gracias por sus respuestas, mi problema es el siguiente.

Estoy intentando crear un archivo con clases para realizar algunas simples operaciones, la carpeta del proyecto contiene un index y dos archivos contenidos dentro de una carpeta anidada, pero a la hora de ejecutar mi codigo me genera el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in "..\index.php" on line 6.

**//Archivo index.php ... Directorio: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso PHP\Poo\Clases'**

```
<?php

require_once 'libs/Matematica/Aritmetica.php';
require_once 'libs/Matematica/Financiera.php';

use libs\Matematica\{Aritmetica, Financiera};

$obj = New Financiera(1000, 0.25 , 1);
$obj1 = new Matematica();

var_dump($obj->tea());


var_dump($obj1->suma(2,3));


?>
```

**//Archivo Aritmetica.php Directorio: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso PHP\Poo\Clases\libs\matematica'**

```
<?php
namespace libs\Matematica;

class Aritmetica {

    public function suma(float $a, float $b) : float {
        return $a + $b; 
    }

    public function resta(float $a, float $b) : float {
        return $a - $b; 
    }

    public function multiplicacion(float $a, float $b) : float {
        return $a * $b; 
    }

    public function division(float $a, float $b) : float {
        return $a / $b; 
    }

    public function EsPar(float $n){

        return $this->calcularParoImpar($n);
    }

    public function EsImpar(float $n){
        return $this->calcularParoImpar($n, false);
    }

    private function CalcularParoImpar(float $n, bool $par = true ) : bool {
        if ($par) {
            return $n % 2 === 0; 
        } else {
            return $n % 2 !== 0;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**//Archivo Financiera.php Directorio: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso PHP\Poo\Clases\libs\matematica'**

```
<?php
namespace Libs\Matematica;

class Financiera {
    #Propiedades
     private $capital;
     private $tasa;
     private $periodo;

    public function __construct(
        float $capital,
        float $tasa,
        int $periodo
    ) {
        this->capital = $capital;
        this->tasa = $tasa;
        this->periodo = $periodo;   
    }

    function __destruct() {
        echo 'Ha finalizado el calculo para financiera';
    }

    public function tea () : float {
        return this->capital *((1 + this->$tasa) ** this->$periodo);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Esta sintaxis `use libs\Matematica\{Aritmetica, Financiera};` solo es soportada por php7 ¿qué versión utilizas tu?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Xampp con la versión de php 7.07. Soy nuevo en el tema con xammp y pienso que quiza mi configuración sea la erronea puesto que cualquier archvo que manejo para php7+ me surgen errores. alguna ayuda recomendacion?

Comment: Crea una página que se llame `phpinfo.php` en donde tengas tus archivos de xampp, este archivo va a tener lo siguiente: `<?php phpinfo() ?>` lo visitas desde tu navegador y podrás que versión de php tienes

Comment: Baia Baia Tienes toda la boca llena de razón sobre la versión de PHP instalada en mi sistema. De verdad te agradezco el tiempo para tu respuesta y ayudarme con este error de un mortal. Tambien agradezco a esos heroes sin capa que redactaron y me ayudaron a poner el espaciado correcto este mundo es mejor gracias a todos ustedes..

Comment: De nada, termina el [tour] para que puedas ganar otra medalla, y recuerda siempre basarte en [ask] para tus preguntas :D